# Ext4 All data deleted, can't recover

Tags: filesystems, ext4, data-recovery, superblock, testdisk

I don't know what I did, but I made a disaster and lost around 50000 family pictures. There was inside a raid1.

`ls` return just 2 files:

```
root@NAS:/srv/dev-disk-by-label-RAID1# ls
aquota.group  aquota.user
```

I can use `photorec` but I will lose names and folders.

I tried `testdisk`, and can see all deleted files but can't recover them, testdisk return `0 copied, 0 failed`

[image]

I want to use another superblock because I think there is a problem with the filesystem.

Comment: 1. Don't mount the drive or try to write anything to it. 2. Buy and use https://www.r-studio.com/ which in my experience is the best data recovery utility.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have tried photorec and undelete and they don't recover files with original names and paths, that's big problem for me as i will need to check each picture.. that's why i think i need to backup another file system with superblock but don't know how to do. Anyway if it does not work i will try rstudio. Thanks

Comment: @JeanChristopheRichter If at all possible, create a verbatim byte-level copy of the partition using `dd` or [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org), for safeguarding the current state.

Comment: Thank you, it's already done, i have made a image.dd

Comment: You can run some scripts to sort by type. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec and if photos you can use date inside photo to rename file. https://exiftool.org/  When I copy files from iphone, it does not have correct file date, so I run my own script to correct that with find & exiftool.

Comment: I didn't think about using the exif's thank you. There is so much files that i will try to recover old file system before

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov i wanna thank you for let me know r-studio. it's the only software that i tried who can retrieve files with original folders and name.